# How to feed the classifier to train on Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, feed

I read the images that will be used to train my classifier in a Dataset as follows:

```
filename_strings = []
label_strings = []
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('training'):
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_strings.append(dirname + '\\' + filename)
        label_strings.append(dirname)

filenames = tf.constant(filename_strings)
labels    = tf.constant(label_strings)
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset_train = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

_parse_function:

```
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def _parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
    return image_decoded, label
```

But now I am not able to feed the train step.:

```
# Create the Estimator
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/model")
# Set up logging for predictions
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Train the model
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x= {"x": dataset_train },
    y= dataset_train,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True)
mnist_classifier.train(
    input_fn=train_input_fn,
    steps=200,
    hooks=[logging_hook])
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial [A Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers)  but with my own image set.

Can I not use the dataset directly to feed the train step? I mean, I just have a tensor with the feature and label for each image.

Comment: For `numpy_input_fn` your dataset is expected in `numpy`, so `_parse_function` must return images as numpy arrays

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you refer to reads the data into a numpy array (see [the code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py)) and pass the input with `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`. This is the easiest way.

However, if you prefer to operate with tensors from the very beginning, it's possible as well using a [custom input function](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn). Here's a trivial example:

```
def read_images(batch_size):
  # A stub. Should read the next batch, shuffle it, etc
  images = tf.zeros([batch_size, 28, 28, 1]) # 4-rank tensor
  labels = tf.ones([batch_size])             # 1-rank tensor (not one-hot encoded)
  return images, labels

def simple_input():
  x, labels = read_images(batch_size=10)
  return {"x": x}, labels

tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

classifier.train(input_fn=simple_input,
                 steps=10,
                 hooks=[logging_hook])
```